# firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword() - completes before a using any other rxJs operators

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs6, switchmap

I am using angularFireAuth for authentication and the firestore as the DB.

My use-case is pretty simple:

1. register a new user with `email` and `password` using firebase JS SDK methods.
2. On successful registration, save the user's info in the `firestore` database.

If I would simply use the promise, It works fine. However rest of the app, the code mostly uses observables and It simply feels unnatural to use promise in the middle since most of the APIs either consume`observable` or return `observable`.

So I started to convert these `()=> promise<void>` types to `observable<void>` using the `defer` - Rxjs

Here is an example:

user.service.ts

```
  export const USER_COLLECTION = 'users';
  private userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection;
  constructor(    private db: AngularFirestore  ) {
    this.userCollection = this.db.collection(USER_COLLECTION);  
}    

//save user in firestore db  

saveUser(user: User): Observable {    
  return defer(() =>        
   this.userCollection.doc(user.UID).set(classToPlain(user))    
  );  
}
```

The registeration method is like:

```
registerUser(value: { email: string, password: string }): Observable {       
    return from(firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email,value.password))      
              .pipe(switchMap(user => this.db.saveUser(user)))  
}
```

*the switchMap never calls the `this.db.saveUser` . As a result, the user never is saved to firestore*

... and in a component, I subscribe to the `registerUser method`

```
 this.subs.sink = this.authService.registerUser(this.loginForm.value)      
.subscribe();
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, The `switchMap` operator should ideally unsubscribe the last observable(`from..`) and should subscribe to the `DB.saveUser`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `defer` instead of `from` to get a Cold Observable and instead of using the `then` syntax for Promise, I used `async - await`.

```
return defer(async () => {
  const cred = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password);
  return cred.user;
})
  .pipe(
    map(user => this.transformService.transformUser(user)),
    switchMap(user => this.saveUser(user))
  );
```

worked like a charm!